# Prove that if $a^{(n-1)/2}\equiv\pm1\pmod{n}$, then $\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)\equiv a^{(n-1)/2}\pmod{n}$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, jacobi-symbol

Let $a,n\ \in \mathbb Z$ and suppose that $n>1$ is odd, $n\equiv3\pmod{4}$, and that $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

> Prove that if $a^{(n-1)/2}\equiv\pm1\pmod{n}$, then
>   $$\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)\equiv a^{(n-1)/2}\pmod{n}$$

I have no idea how to prove the desired result. I started by noting that $a$ is therefore not a Miller-Rabin Witness by our assumption. Further we know that for $n=2^kq+1$, $k=1$ since $n\equiv3\pmod{4}$. However, putting this all together I just got back to the initial assumption that $a^{(n-1)/2}\equiv\pm1\pmod{n}$.

Should I focus more on the other side of the equation (i.e. the Jacobi Symbol)? I was thinking this but I couldn't figure out anything to do with it other than to break it up into:
$$ \left(\frac{a}{n}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{a}{n}\right) $$
This didn't seem to take me very far either, however, since 
$ \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=1$ and $\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right)=-1$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks close to [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

Comment: yeah it's essentially the same thing without $n$ necessarily being a prime number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, we have $\exists q\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n=4q+3$.

---

Now, let's assume $a^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \equiv \color{blue}{1} \pmod{n}$ then 
$$a^{2q+1}\equiv 1\pmod{n} \Rightarrow 
\left(\color{red}{a^{q+1}}\right)^2\equiv a\pmod{n}$$
which means $\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)=\color{blue}{1}$.

---

Similarly, let's assume $a^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \equiv \color{blue}{-1} \pmod{n}$ then 
$$a^{2q+1}\equiv -1\pmod{n} \Rightarrow 
\left(\color{red}{a^{q+1}}\right)^2\equiv -a\pmod{n}$$
which means $\left(\frac{-a}{n}\right)=1$. [But](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol#Properties) $1=\left(\frac{-a}{n}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)$ and $$\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}=(-1)^{2q+1}=-1$$
as a result $\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)=\color{blue}{-1}$.

Comment: how did you get $(a^{q+1})^2\equiv a \pmod{n}$?

Comment: did you just multiply both sides by $a$?

Comment: @joseph yes, multiply both sides by $a$.